# View reference count of a method in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2015

For Visual Studio 2015 Community, is there some extension that can allow to see the class methods reference count like Code lens feature (in the Professional or higher editions)?

It must not be located above the method signature like Code Lens it can be also in a separate window with thy class methods list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing CodeLens references count in VS 2015 Community edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144785/missing-codelens-references-count-in-vs-2015-community-edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier this month I get an update notification in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition 
of [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx). After install CodeLens was activated. I'm in doubt about that this is intention of Microsoft. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33144974/5198722).