# How to switch on CodeLens in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017. 
I cannot find any option to switch on CodeLens. Is this feature removed from this version?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CodeLens is not available in the Community editions.  You need Professional or  higher to switch it on.

In VS2015, one way to "get" CodeLens was to install the SQL Server Developer Tools (SSDT) but I believe this has been rectified in VS2017.

Comment: I find it quite bizarre that Microsoft decided not to include CodeLens in the Visual Studio Community Editions when this feature is already available in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: How else are they going to get you to buy the $11,000 version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I agree, that the higher Visual Studio versions are not cheap, but at least the situation has improved the last years. Actual prize: VS Professional is $499,- and Enterprise is $5999,- the latter including MSDN 1y,  :-) Update for Enterprise is $2569,-. This is not cheap, but more affordable for single professionals IMHO than in earlier years. Additionally, if you are a student, there are possibilities of getting VS for free from your institution.

Comment: _rectified_ -.-

Comment: @Jasen well, I didn't want to say "fixed" :)

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio Community dose not support CodeLens , only Visual Studio
Professional and Visual Studio
Enterprise give this Integrated Development Environment Facility.
For more information go to this link [enter link description here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/)

For Visual information Please See this Image: [Visual Studio
Community supported Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiXfS.png)

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20146825)

Comment: i had also added a screen shot , if any case the Link become invalid.

Answer (score 4):

If you like CodeLens you can install [Visual Studio 2019 *Community*](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

Microsoft has enabled it even for the Community edition. See **Integrated Development Environment** on [Visual Studio Comparison](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/). Most features are enabled.

See **CodeLens for Everyone** [What's New in Visual Studio 2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt848632.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

CodeLens is now available since VS 2017 Community Update 8, but it only contains Requests and Exceptions of Application Insights, no References:

From Dante Gagne [MSFT] on Oct 31, 2018 at 05:38 PM:

> The infrastructure for CodeLens has been released in the Visual Studio 2017 Update 8. Please install and let us know your feedback. Please continue to provide feedback and help us make Visual Studio even better.

[Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351557/add-codelens-even-in-visual-studio-2017-community.html)

It can be enabled in the Text Editor Options under All Languages --> CodeLens --> Enable CodeLens

Answer (score 2):

Resharper has "Find Usages" and "Find Usages Advanced". The default keyboard shortcut for "Find Usages" is Shift+F12. If you can live with using that shortcut instead of clicking on the reference link above a type then you're good to go. I've moved the results window from the bottom to the left and enabled auto-hide.
Good enough for me.

Comment: Useful hint, I used it myself for long time, but this is not an answer. CodeLens is not just about finding usages, and no one asked about search/lookup/etc. It also shows results of unit tests, plugins/extensions may inject more contextual data into it, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Community 2019 a lesser CodeLens version is available:

[image]

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/

Visual Studio Community 2019:

[image]

Visual Studio Professional 2019:

[image]