# Dose visual studio 2017 community have reference counter?

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed 2017 community version, but can't find the reference counter like: [image]

Is there any switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a generic reference counting feature, it's just one of the features of CodeLens. CodeLens is only available in Visual Studio 2015 Pro and above. In Visual Studio 2013 it was a Ultimate-only feature.

Ref: [Missing CodeLens references count in VS 2015 Community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144785/missing-codelens-references-count-in-vs-2015-community-edition/33144974#33144974)