# How to enable code usages in file for Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Before in Visual Studio with Resharper I used to have code usages in file, so I could click on a link above a class for example and see the usages of that specific class.

This is something that disappeared for me lately and is very annoying since I am so used to it. I added a picture below that illustrates what I mean. Where there is white clutter, it used to be a usage link that I could click that would open up a small popup.

**How can I enable this in Resharper?** I have searched the web and in the settings, but to no avail. I have the latest stable version of VS and Resharper.

Thanks in advance!

[image: image that display where they usage could be]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is Visual Studio feature, not Resharper.

Try:
In Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise Enable CodeLens by doing this-
Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens
This link has more details: [Visual Studio 2017: Display method references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796941/visual-studio-2017-display-method-references)

Answer (score 0):

by using resharper. You can use the shortcut key Shift + f12 to find the number of references associated with your code.

[image: number of references]