# Getting definition of an Interface Function

Tags: c#, function, interface

i have a Code from another Person and i need a specific Part of it. The part I need, is in the `start()` Function. The Code with the start Function is this:

```
using System;

namespace base.First
{
  public interface IFirst
  {

    void start();

  }
}
```

If I right click the Function and "Go to definition" -or clicking something else in the "right click menu" I only come to the same Class that i showed you above.

Does anyone know a way, how i can see the Code from the `start()` Function? I tried following:
- Go to definition
- I also tried it with ReSharper

The language is C#.

Comment: This is an interface, so you are probably looking for _implementations_. In VS there should be something above the line "void start();" that says "X References | ... " where X is a number. You can left click that to see where it is used and by clicking one item in the list you can jump there.

Comment: nah there is just an Event handler Above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are more than one implementations of the `IFirst` interface when you use "Go to implementations" command there should be a window opened (usually at the bottom) saying "'IFirst' Implementations" listing all the types that implement this interface. 
In case you are using the Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise edition (or any VS 2019) I suggest you turn on the option to see all references of a method (or property) above its implementation. Here you can find more information on how to turn it on: 
[Visual Studio 2017: Display method references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796941/visual-studio-2017-display-method-references)

Comment: Mhh i get this Error `The Symbol has no implementations.` Idk what this means.

Comment: Is it important to know for you that this Function is implementet by a custom Library?