# how to remove reference count in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

How to remove the reference count in vscode?

[image: reference count]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017: Display method references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796941/visual-studio-2017-display-method-references)

Comment: @dmedine Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio

Comment: @Llama I guess that answer isn't very helpful then.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you only need to disable code references for C#, you can do this by using vs code settings or by changing the user settings file.

1. Via VS Code settings:
   Go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** and search for "*csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled*" and make sure its unchecked.

[image]

2. Editing the settings file:
   Go to your user settings file which is in following path:

   %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

Edit following attribute to false to disable code reference count:

```
"csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false
```

Comment: vscode has a settings editor. No need to manually edit config files.

Comment: @MikeLischke yes, you are right, we can change that directly from settings as well. I have edited the answer as well. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Vue.js have this too in the Volar extension, if u want to disable, you can just add this line on your settings.json:

```
  "volar.codeLens.references": false
```

Or search for it on settings menu instead :)