# How to disable references messages in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VsCode, x references appear just above a class, method, or attribute. How to disable the display of these messages?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB3Sf.png)]

I tried to disable it in Editor > Show References, but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove reference count in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402959/how-to-remove-reference-count-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typing codelens in the search and ticking the first checkbox in the results

**"editor.codeLens": false**

Comment: This is no different than the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371578/337315