# See all specialized uses of a generic class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I have a `class Blah<T>` and I would like to see all specialized uses of Blah, that is, all classes `T`'s such that `Blah<T>` is used.

As I use visual studio (2019) I could obviously search for "Blah<" or do something fancier with regular expressions (this would potentially list multiple times a same use though), but is there rather by chance a visual studio 2019 functionality allowing for that, or a resharper one for doing the same ? (I am using resharper 2019.2.3.)

Comment: The `XX References` button above the class?

Comment: I don't have this button.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio you have it. Its a link right above the `public class B....` Shortcut is put cursor on class name and hit `Alt + 2`. Or right click on  class name and use `Find All References`

Comment: just worth mentioning the _link above class_ is from what is called `CodeLens` and it is available to all edition of Visual Studio as of 2019 which is not true for previous years where community edition did not have it. You and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57094372/2748412) on how to enable codelens. You certainly have loaded an older version profile or Visual Studio as it's on by default.

Comment: As well as code lens, using Find All References from the context menu will also list all cases.

Comment: Resharper's Shift+F12 shortcut?

Comment: I actually wasn't able to see the references in questions even after activating them. I repaired the Vs install and it worked after. Thx also for the resharper pointer !